# Can you have a shark companion out when not in water?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, druid

I was thinking of being a druid and having a shark companion. My question is if they only know swim how can they be on land? It has no land speed indicated.

I know this seems like a simple concept but I don't want to be told no because they can't walk. If so would having a shark as a companion be of a true benefit if you do most quests on land? I am aware there are aquatic campaigns but that's not all I will want to play.

Comment: Very related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/witch-octopus-familiar

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38037/how-can-a-land-based-druid-have-a-surviving-shark-animal-companion

Answer (score 6):

A [shark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/shark/shark) is [aquatic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Aquatic) (and not amphibious), so it suffocates on land just like a badger companion under the ocean would drown. In addition, it has no land speed, making it unable to accompany you on your journeys.

If you can somehow overcome its suffocation problem and its flopping-around-uselessly problem, only then would it be useful (and [likely terrifying](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sky_shark)) for a land-based druid's adventures.

Comment: Aboleth's lung + Wings of Flying, perhaps?